# How to create a label for a react native switch component?

Tags: css, react-native

Usually you can use the label html element to add labels for web apps. How can you achieve this result in react native?

Here is the react native switch component I'm using: https://reactnative.dev/docs/switch

When I try manually adding text as a label it doesn't format it properly. Is this just a css issue or is there a label element I can use?

```
<Text> Deliverable?</Text>
   <Switch
     trackColor={{ false: '#767577', true: '#81b0ff' }}
     thumbColor={isEnabled ? '#f5dd4b' : '#f4f3f4'}
     ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
     onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
     value={isEnabled}
     style={styles.switch}
  />
```

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@vatsalsoni/switch
Working fine here
Could to add you VIew component

Comment: Ok so its just a styling problem. Wasn't sure if they had a separate label component in react native.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how you try to add manually a `Text` as a `Label`, but as you said, you have to play with `Switch`, `Text`|`Image`... and some `Styles` to get what you want.

This is a simple example of code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Switch } from "react-native"

export function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false)

  const onValueChange = value => {
    setValue(value)
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.switchContainer}>
        <Text>{value ? "ON" : "OFF"}</Text>
        <Switch
          style={styles.switch}
          onValueChange={onValueChange}
          value={value}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  switchContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  switch: {
    marginLeft: 10
  }
})
```

[image]